# Meaning of deny

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

What does "deny" mean in football context?

Could you explain what "deny" mean in football context?

> 51' SAVE! De Gea **denies** Maddison with a brilliant diving stop. The midfielder curls a free-kick towards the top-right corner from 25 yards, but De Gea gets across and palms it away from danger. So close to an equaliser from the Foxes.

[Leicester vs Man Utd goal.com](https://www.goal.com/en/match/leicester-city-v-manchester-united/7cvyt8m2h0wjw6uc4n2x0cavo)

Answer (score 4):

John Lawler wrote in a comment

> Metaphorically, it's a debate, and De Gea has just prevented Maddison from proving a point. *Deny* is a speech verb (one can deny a proposition by saying it's false), but metaphorically it means to keep anyone from doing something they want, try, or intend to do; equivalent to *prevent*, but the direct object is the agent who or which fails.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the meaning related to belief, [a meaning of "deny"](https://www.google.com/search?q=deny%20meaning&oq=deny%20meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l7.7120j1j7&client=ms-android-samsung-gj-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) is:

> refuse to give or grant something to someone

So the opposing player attempts to score a goal and the goalkeeper blocks it (denies) or fails to block it (allows). Both terms are used frequently in sports, especially football. This is true even if the goalkeeper is not intentionally "allowing" the goal.